# django-threadedcomments: 'RequestContext' object has no attribute 'META'

Tags: python, django, django-comments, threaded-comments

I try to use django-threadedcomments
But when I add into template 
{% load threadedcomments_tags %}

I get error on this lines 
{% render_comment_list for publication %}
{% render_comment_form for publication %}

> 'RequestContext' object has no attribute 'META'

But if I use django_comments with {% load comments %} it's work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing - when you use {% load comments %} in your template, it uses django.contrib.comments to render the page. When you use  {% load threadedcomments_tags %}, it uses django-threadedcomments library.

Which version of Django do you use? It seems like django-threadedcomments is not compatible with Django 1.10. If you want to continue using it, you need to make own adjustments in the django-threadedcomments code, due to change in render_to_string method. Here are some more insights into that: https://github.com/HonzaKral/django-threadedcomments/issues/78

The other solution is to go back to Django 1.9, if you don't mind the version at this point. It works fine.